# Read stories/posts using instagram API

Tags: api, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api, instagram-story

I wanted to get all the stories for an user using Instagram API. Not the stories posted by the user but by the people he/she is following similar to how i am able views stories after i log in to my account.Is there any API from Instagram to do that.

Same doubt for getting posts as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any API from Instagram to do that.

No.

One [end-point](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/stories/) associated with retrieving stories is working with *that* Instagram account's page token. Which means you can only collect the same account's stories, none other than that.

Comment: But will this give stories of this whom the user is following. I guess this won't ?

Comment: Don't you read how I started? NO.